# Get enum's value as font style

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created an enum of 3 fonts as shown in script below. I am trying to assign the respective selected font from the inspector window. Unfortunately I do not get the value selected, instead I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class TextScript : MonoBehaviour {

 public enum fontStyleEnum // your custom enumeration
    {
        Bold, 
        Underline, 
        Italic
    };

    public TMP_Text textMesh; 

    public fontStyleEnum fontStyle;
    
     public void Start(){
        textMesh.fontStyle = FontStyles.fontStyle.value; //I get the error here
    }
}
```

Comment: The [docu](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.2/api/TMPro.FontStyles.html) says `TMP_Text.fontStyle` is of type `TMPro.FontStyles`.

Comment: You haven't given us error you are receiving but I think it is error for invalid type. What type is your variable `fontStyle` of your class `TMP_Text`?

Comment: @AleksaRistic yes it is. It says that FontStyles does not contain a definition for fontStyle.

Comment: You'll need to write conversion code if you insist on using your own enum (a `switch` would work well here). Alternatively, you could just use the `TMPro.FontStyles` enum instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable you are assigning is using enum `TMPro.FontStyles` and you are trying to assign your `fontStyleEnum` type.

Assing it any of `TMPro.FontStyles` enum and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

[FontStyles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/api/TMPro.FontStyles.html) does not have a field called `fontStyle`.

You have to take your enum and cast it to [FontStyles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/api/TMPro.FontStyles.html).
See:

```
public void Start()
{
    textMesh.fontStyle = (FontStyles)fontStyle;
}
```

Comment: nah it's pretty dangerous (not even possible afaik) to simply cast between enums ... you first have to go via `int` and what makes you think that OPs `fontStyleEnum ` and `TMPro.FontStyles` have always the same `int` values for their values? Additionally I think it is actually a flag so you can combine multiple values